# How to calculate aging tolerance of Resistor?

Tags: resistors, resistance, stability, reliability, tolerance

I wanted to calculate the worst case minimum and maximum value of Resistor 1K by considering all  the 
tolerances(initial tolerance,temperature,environmental factors and aging).

Here is the link for the datasheet:

http://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/CHPREZTR.pdf

Based on the datasheet, I found

initial tolerance - 1%

temperature - 100ppm/deg C - Calculated as +0.45% and -0,4% (Based on my system operating temperature range which is between -15 deg C AND 70 deg C)

Environmental factors -10.5%

But I do not know how to calculate the aging tolerance based on the Load Life data which is given as 1% under this condition (+70 °C; 1.5 hours “ON”,
0.5 hours “OFF”; 1000 hours)

Any suggestion how to interpret the datasheet for aging tolerance?

Comment: Depends on material used. Older carbon resistors evaporated, not sure if nowadays metal film resistors have same issue.

Comment: I'm not sure that is a ageing spec.. but it only changes 1%... your tempco is going to be worse.  (You can buy R's with better tempco.)

Comment: It isn't given as 1%, it's given as ≤±(1.0 % + 0.05 Ω) for the stated test. They don't show a chart for the ageing, so it it might start off decreasing then increase, or anything. I suggest you contact the manufacturer - they might have unpublished data.

Answer (score 9):

According to the datasheet, the test is done in compliance with [MIL-STD-202](https://snebulos.mit.edu/projects/reference/MIL-STD/MIL-STD-202G.pdf), method 108 (pp 37-38), condition D (1,000h).

This is an accelerated aging test at (probably) 100% rated power (while "ON") with a duty cycle of 75%. Your operating conditions will almost certainly be more benvolent than these, which in practice means that the stress of your resistor may be lower than the usual assumption.

We know from Arrhenius that each additional 10°C accelerates reactions by an aging factor \$Q_{10}\$, that is:

$$
\frac{t_0}{t_{acc}}=Q_{10}^{\frac{T_{acc}-T_0}{10}}
$$

From that, we can calculate that those 1,000h operating at 100% rated power at 70°C are roughly equivalent (i.e. induce the same aging-related drift) to 31 months (2.583 years) at 100% rated power at 25°C, assuming the usual aging factor \$Q_{10}=2\$.

That amounts to 1% over 2.583 years or an average 3,870 ppm/year at 25°C. You can recalculate this for any operating temperature by using the equation above. Note: this is probably a conservative calculation due to operating conditions.

However, the aging drift does not increase linearly with time, but rather with the square root of time:

$$
\frac{\Delta R}{R}=K\sqrt{t}
$$

Recall that the previous calculation of 3,870 ppm/year was an *average* for the 2.583 years of the calculation period, but the actual implicit aging constant at 25°C is K=6,225 \$ppm/\sqrt{year}\$, which is a better case. Note that the aging drift are stronger during the first years, and smoother (slower) afterwards:

- 2.583 years: 10,000 pmm (1,0%) as specified
- 5 years: 13,919 ppm (1,4%)
- 10 years: 19,685 ppm (2,0%)
- 20 years: 27,839 ppm (2,8%)
- 40 years: 39,370 ppm (3,9%)

Comment: And what is your conclusion? Does the resistor drop the resistance or it gains the resistance 3.87ppm/yr?

Comment: Usually the resistance increases. However, the datasheet you've linked states that it's +/-. And beware, it's 3,870 ppm/year, not 3.87!

Comment: By the way, I am not the OP, so I didn't link any datasheet. I just want to tell you, that aging involves a certain chemical or mechanical process, so the resistance change can go just in one direction. As for older carbon resistors, they tend to increase the resistance due to evaporating of the film. My conclusion is that your explanation about +/- 3,870 ppm/yr is not plausible.

Comment: What's not plausible from your POV?

Comment: @Enric Blanco:Can you please explain how you arrived the Value 3870ppm/year.I have difficulty in understanding the terminologies on the equation that you mentioned

Comment: 1% = 10,000 ppm, 10,000 ppm/2.583yr = 3,871 ppm/yr

Comment: In case you're wondering about those 2.583 years, use my first equation: 1000h x 2^[(70-25)/10] = 22,627h = 2.583yr

Comment: And also, using the second equation: K = 10,000 pmm / sqrt (2.583) = 6,225 ppm/sqrt(yr). The extrapolated drift values for 5, 10, 20 and 40 years are respectively K x sqrt(5), K x sqrt(10), K x sqrt(20), K x sqrt(40). The values are those shown at the end of the answer.

Comment: OK, I've corrected an error in the first equation. Numerator and denominator where swapped in the left side of the equality. Sorry.

Comment: Could you please provide a source for your formula and  "We know from Arrhenius that each additional 10°C accelerates reactions by an aging factor Q10" Vishay has a different value in this AppNote https://www.vishay.com/doc?28809

Comment: Very well thought out answer. Thank you. Now though, let's look at the aging of resistors which are used at 10% of their rating, not 100%. I have not found an equation which describes the effect. but, I've repaired equipment I've had in the field for over 30 years. I took out and measured the resistors on a broken board. They all have less than 0.1% change from the original value. The NASA reliability guidelines tell me that those resistors should have drifted far more after 30 years. Looks like the NASA guidelines are worst case added to worst case added to worst case.